# File Explorer item selection visually changed after Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-v1703

Before the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703), the box that highlights an item in File Explorer stopped at the end of the file name. Now, it extends all the way across the width of the column. Is there a way to change it back?

Before:
[image: Before]
After:
[image: After]

Comment: I don’t understand this.  Can you post images (screenshots)?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to say that before when you selected a file in File Explorer, only the filename was "highlighted" (to show which file[s]) is selected...but now the entire row is highlighted.  Still...a screenshot would be helpful for others to see visually what you mean.

Comment: I believe the phenomenon is called "full row select". Love it or hate it, it seems. This site claims to have a fix, but with side effects: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-full-row-select-auto-arrange-folders-windows-10/

Comment: Probably only affects the “List” view. Who uses that anyway? :D